# Are ClassLoader Memory Leaks As Bad As They Seem?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, classloader

I have been working with java for a long time now, and I am starting to consider memory leaks. I intend to use classloader because I want to make my program more dynamic. After a bunch of googling, I read more about the ugly objects that stay loaded even when you dereference them.

I am concerned about my program having memory leaks. I know that all programs will have some amount of memory leaks, but is java really on the ugly side for leaking memory? My question in that department:

Is java worth dealing with for the memory leaks 
and are the memory leaks in java really as huge as google made them sound?

How can I write my code to keep down memory leaks, like how should I reference objects with classloader and how should I dereference them?

Is there an alternative to classloader without the problems (or as bad of problems) with retaining objects?

Comment: It depends on what you intend to do with the classloader.  Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I intend to use it to make a modular platform for my video game (IE, to add object A you just have to add a class to package B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classloader memory leaks will only affect you if you do a lot of dynamic class loading, one way or another. For example:

- by calling `Class.forName()` repeatedly
- by creating dynamic proxy classes repeatedly
- by repeated hot redeployment of webapps (e.g. with Tomcat)

Most applications don't do these things, and therefore don't have to worry about classloader memory leaks.